# Javascript onchange Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm dreaming of a form who is clever. Example: i'm choosing in a select box option 1 then it will appear a second select box with optionen 1a or 1b or similar. But Maybe if you are using option 2 in the first one, so maybe a textarea appears to help to get the information who matches to the option 2.

I'm new to javascript an i asked google and found a lot of small examples. I did now something like that. But i'm not sure if this is a good idear to work on this way, because that means i have to write my html code for the second select oder textarea in the value part of the first one.

Does anyone know where i should start or how i should sort my functions an vars?

```html
<body>
    <select id="cms">
       <option value="Stiefmütterchen">Stiefmütterchen</option>
       <option value="Primeln">Primeln</option>
       <option value="Tulpen">Tulpen</option>
    </select>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var choosenCMS = document.getElementById('cms');
       cms.onchange = function() 
       {
          var show = document.getElementById('show');
          show.innerHTML = this.value;
       }
    </script>
    
    <div id="show"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: just asking, have you tried jQuery?

Comment: You will need to learn to build `<select>` tags on-the-fly from source arrays. Then you can use a 2D array to store all your options and sub-options. This array will be either hard-coded or dynamically populated from JSON (or XML) file.

Comment: jQuery, not yet tried. But i thought, that could be a possibilty to. But i don't know how to code this right now, but if you think it is worth, it could be a solution. thank you

Comment: What do you mean with build tags on-the-fly from source arrays? thanks for your help you offering me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple example, you can do this by finding the `value` of the first `select` and using an `if` statement to show/hide other form elements like so:

**HTML**

```
<select id="cms">
   <option>Choose One</option>
   <option value="one">One</option>
   <option value="two">Two</option>
   <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>    

<select id="more">
   <option value="one-a">One A</option>
   <option value="two-b">Two B</option>
   <option value="three-c">Three C</option>
</select>

<textarea></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
$("#cms").change(function(){
   var grabVal = $(this).val();
    if(grabVal == "one"){
       $("#more").show();
        $("textarea").hide();
    }else if(grabVal == "two"){
        $("textarea").show();
       $("#more").hide();
    }else{
        $("textarea").hide();
       $("#more").hide();           
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#more, textarea{
   display: none;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/30b934wd/2/)

Comment: that is exactly what i'm looking for. And very easy to design, because i have the regular html code. Am i right, that your code is jquery and i have to load that first? Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help. Yes it's jquery so makes you you load the library before the code

Comment: Your code really works well. But there is one question left. When i try it in live, so every element will be loaded and after the first select it will worked correctly. How can i say the form that only the first selector will be shown, when a user is opening the page?